Can you reason the equivalence principle from SR?
So for the past few days I've been reading on "why is special relativity incompatible with gravity?".
Most answers are something along the lines of "special relativity doesn't have curved spacetime", but the issue is that I'd have to wonder why Einstein was even thinking about such things.
Since special relativity is completely fine with accelerations, my immediate thought for modeling gravity would be to simply apply a relativistic acceleration, ending up with something like the rindler coordinates from the falling object's viewpoint.
At this point the people would say that the issue is that such a model fails to accurately predict the effects of gravity, but then again they acknowledged that Einstein's formulation of GR didn't come from an attempt to match experiment, calling it "aesthetic preference" or something of the like.
Is there any reason to be naturally drawn towards the equivalence principle out from special relativity, or are they completely separate concepts that Einstein happened to join together?
Was there any obvious violation that the relativistic acceleration model produced such that Einstein had to ponder a different theory?
I'm aware that there's probably no historical basis for that specifically, it's more of a question about the connection between SR and GR and if there's really a good way of progressing from the first to the latter without the immediate assumption that gravitational frames are inertial or that experiment suggests it.
Any answers are greatly appreciated!

Special relativity can deal with accelerating bodies in inertial frames. General relativity is about accelerating frames. For that you need a completely new formulation. SR is not enough.

@Prahar That is not entirely true. R can deal with accelerated reference frames as long as the spacetime is flat. In fact, in 1909 before GR was formulated, Max Born noted that the formulas for hyperbolic motion can be used as transformations into a "hyperbolically accelerated reference system" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates#History

@KDP - That is already going outside the framework of SR and I would put those developments as the initial seeds of GR.

@Prahar How is that going outside the framework of SR? SR can deal with accelerated reference frames. SR just means the spacetime is flat

With hindsight, Rindler coordinates have a lot in common with the Schwarzschild metric of GR. When we look at the equation for the proper time of the accelerating Rindler observers, we can note that clocks 'lower down' appear to tick slower than clocks 'higher up'.
We can also note that inertial objects follow a trajectory that takes then towards x=0 as seen by the accelerated observer's, so objects appear to fall with no proper acceleration or force acting on them, which is key ingredient of GR and is in fact the equivalence principle in disguise. (It was hiding there all along). Historically Einstein analysed a version of Rindler's coordinates in 1907 and came up with equivalence principle the same year, so the exact order he came to his conclusions is not certain.

One of the most distinguishing features of GR compared to Newtonian gravity is that GR predicts light curves in a gravitational field. This is not possible in Newtonian physics, because the gravitational force is a function of the mass of the falling object and light does not have mass. The fact that light curves can be seen in the diagram above. In the Rindler chart on the left, I have drawn the ingoing and outgoing light paths as diagonal world lines as in normal but I have added a vertical line that represents a horizontally moving light ray. this is unusual approach so I will explain it a little more. The vertical line represent a light ray moving parallel to the Y axis that is orthogonal to both the X and T axes and not shown on the chart. Its X component remains constant and on the chart above we only see its T component advancing. This means the light ray falls in just the same way as any inertial falling object, such as those represented by the vertical blue dashed world lines. When we look at the point of view of an accelerating Rindler observer as depicted in the chart on the right, we can see that inertial objects rise to an apogee and fall back down again and the world line of the light ray depicted in red behaves in exactly the same way.
We can also see that the Rindler coordinates predict a sort of horizon, where once a falling object crosses the x=0 line it can not be seen and it can never return to the x>0 region.
Of course in those days the connection between Rindler's coordinates and gravity was not so obvious. Gravitational time dilation was not measured until the Pound-Rebka experiment was carried out over 50 years later. The gravitational bending of light was not confirmed until Eddington carried out his experiment observing an eclipse of the moon about 4 years after GR was published. The idea of black holes and event horizons was not suspected by anybody until Schwarschild published his metric in 1916.
So why wasn't Rindler's coordinate system immediately latched on to as close candidate for SR in a gravitational context? Well Rindler's coordinates for all their similarities to a gravitational field has its problems that would have obvious even back then. One immediate difference between his coordinates and a gravitational field is that the acceleration of the observes id proportional to $1/X$, while the acceleration of observers in a gravitational field experience proper acceleration proportional to $1/X^2$. Can we adapt Rindler coordinates to take the squared acceleration of gravity into account? Not easily. Take a look at the chart below:

I have superimposed the word lines (blue dashed) of observers that have proper acceleration proportional to $1/X^2$. The problem becomes immediately obvious. The accelerated world lines cross over each other! That obviously isn't going to work.
From 1907 to about 1913, little progress was made on generalising SR to include gravity, until Einstein started considering rotational motion in his turntable thought experiment. The point of view of an accelerating observer riding on the perimeter of the turntable also has some things in common with the point of view of a gravitational observer. Just as in Rindler coordinates, the cocks of observers 'lower down' (where the proper acceleration is greatest) run slower than clocks 'higher up'. We can imagine the turntable experiment being carried out in space so that we can ignore the effects of real gravity. When we do this, we can note that inertial objects that are moving parallel to the plane of the turntable (but not touching it) almost inevitably end up at the perimeter, so they appear to fall without any forces acting on them. The exception is an inertial object that is not moving relative to the centre of the disk. This object appears to move in a circle that is a constant distance from the centre, from the point of view of the accelerated observers. This hints at the possibility of orbiting without the involvement of forces. There are however, many problems with equating the point of view of the accelerated observers moving in a circle with the point of view of gravitational observers. It is impossible for them to synchronise their clocks globally, the one way speed of light is anisotropic and the proper acceleration experienced by observers on the disk is not proportional to $1/X^2$.
Nevertheless, Einstein found an intriguing aspect of the disk that he considered worth pursuing in detail and which eventually led to him GR. He noticed that the perimeter of the rotating disk, as measured by the accelerated observers was proportional to $\gamma 2 \pi R$ and not the expected $2 \pi R$. This suggested that geometry is not Euclidean in an accelerating reference frame. Einstein was not familiar with non-Euclidean geometry, so he had to enlist the help of some mathematical friends to teach him. Once he had done that, he started to make rapid progress and published GR (which incorporated the non Euclidean nature of curved space) less than two years later.

Ok so firstly I can recommend reading some beginning chapters of general relativity books if you are interested in these kinds of questions e.g. Sean M. Carroll's Spacetime and Geometry talks about these types of questions at some point (Most of what I'll write below will be from there if my memory is correct).
The problem with special relativity is twofold, firstly there were experimental differences, especially in planetary movement e.g. the precession of the orbits of planets that had been experimentally tested and needed extreme fine-tuning to be explained. GR gives (with a relatively simple calculation) the correct answer of why this is the case as it does not naturally lead to the elliptical orbits known from Kepler's laws but rather slight deviations of these.
However as far as I remember the main reason is more conceptual and has to do with thinking about the principle of equivalence. One main observation here is that the acceleration due to gravity is independent of the mass of the object thus independent of what object you have there exist preferred (accelerated) trajectories in the spacetime that all freely falling test particles will follow. This is quite special about gravity. Think about electro-magnetism for example. Here there are differently charged objects (e.g. pos. and neg.) so they will behave differently when an electromagnetic force acts upon them. So what Einstein realized is that this should have as a consequence that at least locally (where the gravitational field is homogeneous enough) there should be no way to disentangle uniformly accelerating observers from those in a gravitational field, i.e. we can not separate the two effects. (Note that we can argue that such a frame can only ever exist locally due to inhomogeneities in the gravitational field). In some way this gives a very natural starting point for GR as it seems to force us to give up the idea of treating gravity in the same fashion as e.g. Electromagnetism where we can first set up our "laboratory" (inertial frame) and then add electromagnetism on top to see how our setup behaves. The question is now how we should treat gravity and how we can include the ideas of special relativity in a consistent manner as this should still be valid in regions where gravity can be neglected i.e. whenever the gravitational field does not change by a noticeable amount in the region where we perform experiments.
Personally, I do not believe this to be directly drawn out of special relativity but rather based upon observations that gravity acts universally and combining this with the idea of internal frames that Einstein was thinking about in the framework of Special relativity. I think the second step where relativity really comes in is how we should describe physics in this new concept of local inertial frame.
Hope that helped a bit at least but again for a more consistent and complete treatment I can only recommend reading some beginning chapters in GR books.
